# UIButton not working on the first tap

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I made a custom switch to turn on and off sound effects in my game Optic Combat, but for some reason the button that when tapped, animates the switch moving to a different position, is not working on the first tap. Subsequent taps work, just not the first one.

In the IBAction for the button I have:

```
- (IBAction)theSwitch:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *toggle = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (_toggle == 1) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        audioToggle.frame = CGRectMake(985.0f, 59.0f, audioToggle.frame.size.width, audioToggle.frame.size.height);
    }];

    _toggle ++;
    [toggle setInteger:_toggle forKey:@"toggleState"];
    [toggle synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"audioOn"];

}

else {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        audioToggle.frame = CGRectMake(924.0f, 59.0f, audioToggle.frame.size.width, audioToggle.frame.size.height);
    }];

    _toggle --;
    [toggle setInteger:_toggle forKey:@"toggleState"];
    [toggle synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"audioOn"];

}
}
```

And in the viewDidLoad, checking the state of the switch and adjusting it to show the correct position (on or off):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"audioOn"]) {
    [audioToggle setFrame:CGRectMake(924.0f, 59.0f, audioToggle.frame.size.width, audioToggle.frame.size.height)];
    _toggle = 2;
}
else {
    [audioToggle setFrame:CGRectMake(985.0f, 59.0f, audioToggle.frame.size.width, audioToggle.frame.size.height)];
    _toggle = 1;
}
```

**Edit: I used this to solve my problem, in the IBAction for the button:**

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"audioOn"]) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    audioToggle.frame = CGRectMake(985.0f, 59.0f, audioToggle.frame.size.width, audioToggle.frame.size.height);
    }];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"audioOn"];
}
else {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    audioToggle.frame = CGRectMake(924.0f, 59.0f, audioToggle.frame.size.width, audioToggle.frame.size.height);
    }];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"audioOn"];
}
```

Comment: why dont you use selected boolean value?

Comment: Its a logical error I think. Try my answer..

Comment: I have since switched to a boolean value, I'll see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

In your `viewDidLoad`

```
 if _toggle = 2; 
 frame = CGRectMake(924.0f, 59.0f, audioToggle.frame.size.width, audioToggle.frame.size.height)
```

and

```
if _toggle = 1; 
 frame = CGRectMake(985.0f, 59.0f, audioToggle.frame.size.width, audioToggle.frame.size.height)
```

But in your buttonAction it is different. Interchange in `viewDidLoad` if buttonAction is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Anusha got it. But I also suspect you would easily have found it yourself if you'd chosen a slightly different style. The toggle is either on or off, in other words a perfect match for a boolean. If you had a BOOL named swicthedOn you'd have checks reading if (switchedOn) which would improve readability a lot.

Something like this perhaps:

```
- (IBAction)theSwitch:(id)sender { // Not using the sender for anything (?)
    NSUserDefaults *toggle = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL audioOn = NO; 
    float toggleX = 924.0f;

    if (_switchIsOn) {
        toggleX = 985.0f;
        audioOn = NO; // not strictly necessary but improves readability       
    }
    else {
        toggleX = 924.0f; // not strictly necessary but improves readability
        audioOn = YES;
    }

    _switchIsOn = audioOn;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        audioToggle.frame = CGRectMake(toggleX, 59.0f, audioToggle.frame.size.width, audioToggle.frame.size.height);
    }];

    [toggle setBool:_switchIsOn forKey:@"toggleState"];
    [toggle synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:audioOn forKey:@"audioOn"]; // Not being synchronized
}
```

Yes, I refactored it (and probably introduced a couple of new bugs). Sorry, couldn't help myself...

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out by just starting over. I had previously been using an overly complex method to cycle through a PNG animation, and since I changed to just moving an image across the screen, using just NSUserDefaults was a lot simpler. I wasn't using the sender, I've been slowly removing it from the places it's not needed.

Comment: I'll consider that, I know there's still a lot of cleaning up to do, as I'm learning more I'm seeing more code that needs to be changed or optimized.